# embeding the php value in html string

Tags: php, mysql

I retreive an variable in mysql database using this function

```
function getComplaints(){
        $issues ="";
        $con = mysql_connect($this->dbHost,$this->dbUsername,$this->dbPassword) 
                                                    or die("Database Connection Error!");
        mysql_select_db($this->dbName,$con);

        $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM issues") 
                                                    or die(mysql_error());

        $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            $id = $row['problem_id'];
            $issues = '<input type="submit" value=$id />';
        }

        return $issues;
    }
```

How to do embedd $id in $issues string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change to:

```
...
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $id = $row['problem_id'];
    $issues.= '<input type="submit" value="'.$id.'" />';
}
return $issues;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use string concatenation

```
$issues = '<input type="submit" value="' . $id . '" />';
```